# Initializing planning variables is causing score corruption

Tags: optaplanner, timefold

Since my model takes long time to do the construction heuristics, I have tried to initialize the planning variables beforehand. As a first step to this approach, I have initialized the planning and shadow variables with random initial values from their value range providers. However, I have not checked if there are any constraint violations and also **have not initialized any score value**. When I run in FULL_ASSERT, I can confirm that there is score corruption. Please help me understand why this is happening. If it is due to not initializing the score, then please tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

A very generic answer to a very generic question. There are two tools in Timefold Solver that can help you do what you need:

- A [custom solver phase](https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/optimization-algorithms/optimization-algorithms#customSolverPhase) lets you run your own code instead of construction heuristics. The documentation shows you examples of how to do it properly.
- By calling `SolutionManager.update(...)`, Timefold Solver will call all the right listeners and do all the other things to fill in the shadow variables and the score for you.

In both cases, you'll need to make sure your variable listeners are written properly. If they are, the two tools above will get you cleanly to the other side. If the variable listeners *cause* score corruptions, you'll have to fix them first.